# Add a div to each int in the in the total numbers

Tags: php

I want to add a div (box with style) to each number.

for example lets say `[ ]` is our styled box.
and `1,700,700` is our number.

I want it to look like this:

```
[ 1 ] , [ 7 ][ 0 ][ 0 ] , [ 7 ][ 0 ][ 0 ]
```

Is this even possible to do? if yes, how?
Thanks

Comment: Sure, convert it to a string and write one character at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first convert number to string and than

To do this we need to know first what exactly string is i am quoting this from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29) to explain

> A string is generally understood as a data type and is often implemented as an array of bytes (or words) that stores a sequence of elements, typically characters, using some character encoding. A string may also denote more general arrays or other sequence (or list) data types and structures.

you can do this like

```
<?php
$foo="1,700,700";


for($i=0; $i<strlen($foo); $i++){
  if($foo[$i] != ',')
    echo '[',$foo[$i],']';
  else
    echo',';
}
```

[**live result**](http://codepad.org/ZoKlForw)